# DirectoryEntry does not contain a definition for 'Properties' (.NET CORE 3.1)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, active-directory

I'm trying to get the department property from AD for a specific user. But it says `DirectoryEntry does not contain a definition for 'Properties'`. A lot of examples on stackoverflow use the following code. Why does this not work for me, am I implementing it wrong? I'm using .net core 3.1.

```
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, domainUser.DistinguishedName);
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();                        
string dept = dirEntry.Properties["Department"].Value.ToString();
```

I'm using the following (relevant) imports.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Turns out you have to install `System.DirectoryServices` in nuget. After the install I did:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
```

The `System.Reflection.PortableExecutable` import was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, this is because `System.Reflection.PortableExecutable` has a definition for [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.portableexecutable.directoryentry), when you really want to use [`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry).

But another note: the `department` attribute is not required. If it's empty, `Value` will be `null` and the call to `ToString()` will throw an exception. So you're better off casting to a `string` instead:

```
var dept = (string) dirEntry.Properties["department"].Value;
```

That way, if `department` does not have a value, your `dept` variable will just end up `null` instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Yes, i've been there with the null pointer exception... Thanks for the additional note!